# SQL Server join on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables : TableA and Table B

**TableA**

| batch_identifier (varchar) | batch_status (bit) | dt_utc (datetime) | batch_tasks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| batch_id1 | 0 | 2022-09-15 10:00:00 | 1 |
| batch_id1 | 1 | 2022-09-15 11:00:00 | 1 |
| batch_id2 | 0 | 2022-09-15 10:30:00 | 4 |

**TableB**

| batch_identifier (varchar) | task_status(bit) | task_description(varchar) | task_identifier(varchar) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| batch_id1 | 0 | 2022-09-15 10:00:00 | task_id1 |
| batch_id1 | 1 | 2022-09-15 10:50:00 | task_id1 |
| batch_id2 | 0 | 2022-09-15 10:30:00 | task_id1 |
| batch_id2 | 1 | 2022-09-15 10:35:00 | task_id1 |
| batch_id2 | 0 | 2022-09-15 10:36:00 | task_id2 |
| batch_id2 | 0 | 2022-09-15 10:37:00 | task_id3 |

What I'm trying to do is the following:
Get a table of 'in progress' batches (i.e batch_status = 0) along with the tasks that have been performed. So for instance in the example above the only batch still running is batch_id2 and the associated completed task is task_id1.

So far I've tested this without success:

```
select
*
from
 (
    select
        batch_identifier,
        MAX(CAST(batch_status as int)) as _status
    from
        dbo.TableA
    group by
        batch_identifier
) data
where _status = 0 ??
```

Can you please help with that?

`batch_identifier` and `task_identifier` are SQL index.

Comment: So what are the expected results you are after here?

Comment: Do you need to create table A from table B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using common table expression to get what batch(es) are still in progress. Then I will get the details in TableB and group by batch and task identifier and check that that max value in task status is zero (meaning task is still in-progress).

```
WITH data as (
    select
        batch_identifier 
    from
        dbo.TableA
    group by
        batch_identifier
    having 
        MAX(CAST(batch_status as int)) = 0)  
select
      details.batch_identifier,
      MIN(CAST(details.task_status as int)) as task_status,
      MIN(details.task_description) as task_description,
      details.task_identifier
from 
        dbo.TableB as details
inner join 
        data on data.batch_identifier = details.batch_identifier  
group by
        details.batch_identifier, 
        task_identifier
having
        MAX(CAST(details.task_status as int)) = 0
```

RESULT:

```
batch_identifier    task_status task_description    task_identifier 
----------------    ----------- ----------------    ------------
batch_id2           0           2022-09-15 10:36:00 task_id2
batch_id2           0           2022-09-15 10:37:00 task_id3
```

Comment: OP wants quite opposite list of tasks, that have been already performed, status =1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like one of these?

```
SELECT batch_identifier, db_utc, Zero, One
FROM TableA
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT batch_identifier,
            SUM(CASE WHEN task_status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Zero,
            SUM(CASE WHEN task_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS One
        FROM TableB
        GROUP BY batch_identifier
    ) AS b
        ON a.batch_identifier = b.batch_identifier

SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM TableB b WHERE b.batch_identifier = a.batch_identifier AND b.task_status = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I don't think you need a subquery.

Try:

```
SELECT batch_identifier, task_identifier, MAX(CAST(batch_status as int)) as _status
FROM dbo.TableA a
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB b ON a.batch_identifier = b.batch_identifier AND task_status = 1
WHERE batch_status = 0
GROUP BY batch_identifier, task_identifier
```